# Under what circumstances is the (Cartesian) product of the power set, the power set of the product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find all sets $A$ and $B$ that satisfy
$$ 2^{A \times B} = 2^A \times 2^B  \ .$$

My line of reasoning (I'll use $P()$ notation to avoid confusion):
$P(A \times B)$ has $2^{|A| |B|}$ elements.
$P(A) \times P(B)$ has $2^{|A|}2^{|B|}$ elements, so it remains to find positive integers $x$ and $y$ (representing the cardinalities of each set) such that $$2^{xy} = 2^x2^y$$ whose solution is $x=y=0$ (empty set), or $x=y=2$ (set containing 2 elements).

I've tried plugging in $A= B = \emptyset$, but I get that $$\{\emptyset, \{(\emptyset, \emptyset )\}\} \neq \emptyset \times \emptyset = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\} \ .$$

What's going wrong? Why is this not working?

I'm thinking that these might be necessary but not sufficient conditions for the first equality to hold, but it doesn't seem to work with any combination of 2-element sets. Any thoughts?

Comment: Then it suffieces to solve $2^{mn} +2^{m+n} $. since $|A\times B| = |A||B|$

Comment: That's just a restatement of what I've written.

Comment: Maybe I am overlooking something, but shouldn't there be no such sets simply for type reasons; one is a set of pairs of sets, the other is a set of sets of pairs? Granted this may change using the set-theoretic definition of pairs.

Comment: That's what I thought, but we have defined ordered pairs in terms of sets.

Comment: I think Both set can never be equals in a strict sens for instance just take $A=B =\{0,1\}$. And write everything down you see that the equality is hopeless

Comment: @MrMilkshake And thre are many ways to define pairs via sets and so the solution of your problem depends on this definition. Do you have some specific definition in mind?

Comment: Let $n =|A|$ and $m= |B|$. Then it suffices to solve $$2^{mn} =2^{m+n} $$ since $|A\times B| = |A||B|$

 But $$2^{mn} +2^{m+n}\Longleftrightarrow  mn =m+n\Longleftrightarrow m=n(m-1) $$

But $gcd({m,m-1}) =1$, hence $$n|m$$ and by symmetry  $$m|n$$ 

that is $$n =m$$
>So we have $$ 2^{A \times B} = 2^A \times 2^B  \implies |A|=|B|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets with $2^{A\times B}=2^A\times 2^B$.
Note that $\emptyset\in 2^{A\times B}$, but $\emptyset\notin 2^A\times 2^B$
for any $A,B$: indeed, if $x\in 2^A\times 2^B$, then $x=(S,T)$ where $S\subseteq A$ and $T\subseteq B$, hence $x=\{S,\{S,T\}\}\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: So, are you saying that no such sets exist?

Comment: Yes; well, more precisely, that $2^{A\times B}\not\subseteq 2^A\times 2^B$ for any sets $A$, $B$, so in particular the sets are never equal.

Comment: Why is it that $S \subseteq A$. I know that $S \subseteq P(A)$, but why does it follow from this that $S \subseteq A$?

Comment: It is not true that $S\subseteq P(A)$. The set $P(A)=2^A$ is the set of subsets of $A$.  By definition of the cartesian product, $(S,T)\in P(A)\times P(B)$ implies $S\in P(A)$, hence $S$ is a subset of $A$. In general, the only situation $S\subseteq P(A)$ as well is when $S=\emptyset$ (barring some infinite descent of sets tomfoolery).

Answer (score 2):

First, those sets can't be literally equal. $2^{A \times B}$ contains sets of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ while $2^{A}  \times 2^B$ contains sets of ordered pairs $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

You may be asking whether they have the same cardinality. That happens if and only if 
$$
|A||B| = |A| + |B|,
$$
which is true for finite cardinals only  when both are $0$ or both are $2$.

It's true if $|A|$ is infinite and $|B| \ne 0$ is finite.

If both are countably infinite then it's true: the countable union of countable sets is countable.

I suspect it's true whenever $|A|$ is infinite and $|B| \ne 0$.
I'd have to brush up on [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic) to be sure.

Comment: "If |A| is infinite and |B| is finite it's always true." Well, and $|B|\neq 0$. Any set has empty product with the empty set.

Comment: @user1306 Fixed thanks, and fixed other stuff too.

Comment: Wouldn't it hold only for the empty set?

Comment: @MrMilkshake I'm pretty sure that for cardinals $p \ge q$ with $ p $ infinite you have $pq = p+q = p$.